# Find coordinates of object from different cameras

Tags: python, image, opencv, camera, computer-vision

I’m trying to find coordinates of object from one image in another image.

There are 2 fixed vertically arranged cameras one above the other (for example 10 cm between cameras). They look in the same direction.

Using `calibrateCamera` from OpenCV I found the following parameters for each camera: ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs.

How do I calculate coordinates of an object from an image from one camera in another camera image? This is assuming that this object exists in both camera images.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as a stereo setup and do [stereo calibration](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereocalibrate).

It will provide you with the Rotation and translation between the coordinates of both the cameras, Essential matrix and fundamental matrix.

You can estimate the fundamental matrix using just point correspondences, refer to the following [link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findfundamentalmat)

[Fundamental Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_(computer_vision)) gives you a line in the other image along which a point in the reference image can exist.